# Computing Forecast Accuracy

Tags: forecasting, cross-validation

I have 24 months of data of which the last 12 months I'm using to test the forecast for a rolling forecast with a 12 month window.  Let's say I want to test the accuracy of the forecast at horizon 6 (point 18).  How would I go about doing that?  I've seen error measures that use h=6 and every point to the end of the data set.

I forgot to mention, the forecasts are based on taking 12 months of data and forecasting the 13th month.  Then the window just moves ahead by one month.  Do I assume that I can only look at h=1 forecast accuracy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at horizon 6 you only have 6 out-of-sample values (future values) to measure your forecast against. I would simple predict 1 period out from each of the 12 origins i.e. point 12,13,....23 . Restimate the model/parameters at each of the 12 origins to reflect typical updating . It would be naive to simply use the model/parameters based upon the first 12 values alone.

In this way you get 12 estimates of a 1 period out forecast error. Now if you wished to use a 2 period horizon .. you would have 11 estimates .

Comment: So I assume I calculate forecast accuracy measures, i.e., MSE, MASE etc., on the 12 - 1-step ahead forecasts?

Comment: yes ... and also the Symmetric Mape which is now very popular,

Comment: I thought that was discourage when dealing with values close to zero.

Comment: I also saw that caveat at wikopedia ....  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_mean_absolute_percentage_error